# Deployed website shows it folder file list

Tags: asp.net, deployment, asp.net-mvc-3

I built Deployment package and feed IIS with that, but when I trying to visit my site, I see only files of root folder like FTP
Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a default or index page?  Also, in IIS you should disable directory browsing.